# Problem with writing Test Class For trigger

Tags: apex, unit-test

I am new to Salesforce and trying to write a test class for the trigger I have created but I have never wrote any test class.
Please help me in writing.

**Whenever a SDR create an event the field SDR Original Demo is updated automatically from the picklist of the SDR names**

```
trigger SDRDemoUpdate on Event (before update) {

List<User> userids = new List<User>();


 for (Event obj :Trigger.new)
{
 userids=[Select id,name from user where id=:obj.CreatedById];
 obj.SDR_Original_Demo__c = userids[0].name;

 }
}
```

This is the trigger I have wrote but while uploading it from sandbox it says that I need code coverage and I have write test class. Please help me getting started or any help is appreciated by newbie.

Comment: Here's a starting point. https://developer.salesforce.com/page/An_Introduction_to_Apex_Code_Test_Methods

Comment: Hi Vip, welcome to SFSE! Please take the time to visit the [Help] and read [How do I ask a good question](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). If you post what you've written so far and where you're stuck, I'm confident you'll find plenty of people willing to assist you. There are also [Trailhead Modules](https://developer.salesforce.com/trailhead/modules)
 on triggers and test classes that will hep get you started writing your own test classes. Posting requests to write code for you will get closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, your trigger is not properly written so here is how to do it properly

```
trigger SDRDemoUpdate on Event (before update) {

    Map<ID,Event> records = New Map<ID,Event>([Select CreatedBy.Name From Event Where ID In :trigger.new]);

    for (Event obj :Trigger.new){

        obj.SDR_Original_Demo__c = records.get(obj.id).CreatedBy.Name;

    }
}
```

This takes query out of the loop and bulkifies it..

Now for the test class:

1. Simply create an event
2. Then update it
3. Query for the Event Including the SDR_Original_Demo__c field
4. Assert that it is equal to `userInfo.getName()`

Comment: @crmprogdev I never asked anyone to write a code for me. I was watched few videos and read about Trigger and wrote this code for the first time and I don't have any coding background and for the test class I am totally blank even after going through the basic how to write it and that why I asked for appropriate link that will help me in writing class. I didn't know that this platform is not for the beginners who is a newbie and asking for help.

Comment: @Vip - if you want to thank me please up vote and / or mark as accepted.

Comment: @Vip - This is a great place for beginners but your questions need to be specific as that is what SFSE is designed for. You give it a shot and when you get stuck in a specific spot, you ask about it. Learning the fundamentals is covered in many other sites.